Buddy Boss: logo is moved from top menu to left-side menu when I try to integrate the left-side menu
I am currently creating a page in buddy boss - an extension of WordPress - as a part of an internship, I am not well known in neither buddy boss or WordPress in general.
I have chosen a theme where there is both a top menu and a left-side menu. However my logo keeps being pushed down to the left-side menu, where I'd prefer it in the top menu.
I have attached a screenshot for reference.
Any Ideas of how I can move it?
screenshot of logos current placement
I tried to change from a manually added side-menu to the "father"-version of the theme, nothing changed in the placement of the logo.
I tried reloading the logo, but that (obviously) didn't change anything either. I could not seem to find a place where I could decide the placement.
I am not afraid of entering the code behind it and move it "manually", however since it is a project for my internship I need to make sure that I do it the right way and not my own messy coding-beginner way ;-)

I found a solution. I am not sure why or how it works, but it works.
Under the path BuddyBoss -> Theme Options -> Buddy Panel -> show logo in buddy panel.
I guess my buddypanel was my left-menu, and by removing it from there it returned to its original placement.

